# sql search query containing first name should first in search

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have one employee table containing data like below

```
Id Name
1  Yogesh
2  Darshan
3  Haresh
4  Ramesh
5  Suresh
6  Ashvin
```

i want to search name from employee table.
my query is

```
SELECT Name FROM Client_Master WHERE Name LIKE'%" + txtname.text + "%'";
```

now i search A on text box then it display first Darshan, Haresh ..Before Ashvin..

My question is if i press A on textbox then first record sholud be Ashin after than Darshan, Haresh, ....will come..

So please suggest me query regarding this.

Comment: Did you try adding an `ORDER BY` clause? `ORDER BY Name ASC` should do the trick.

Comment: beat me to the punch @SchmitzIT. I see no reason why simply a order by wouldn't do exactly that

Comment: I don't think an `Order By` would work. What if he typed the letter 'S' instead of 'A'? He'll still get Ashvin 1st!

Comment: It's not clear from his explanation what he actually wants. Does he just want an order by or an order by based on the letter pressed?

Comment: I am clear dear, I want to search record first which letter i type in textbox it should display first as a record

Comment: Maybe what is also needed with the order by is to remove the preceeding wildcard from the query?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection.
2. Add an `ORDER BY ID` if you want to order by name.

   ```
   var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Client_Master WHERE Name LIKE'%' + @name +'%' ORDER BY Name");

   cmd.Parameters.Add("@name ", txtname.text);
   ```

Comment: If OP type 'S', don't you think Yogesh will appear before Suresh?

Comment: no this is not working..it search by ID, and Ashvin ID is 6 so it should display Ashvin last instead of First..

Comment: What should it display? I am not clear on what the order should be?

Comment: Read it again. is it by name what you need?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to queries, they will (mostly) return data exactly as you specify it, but sorted based on how the physical data is sorted in the table (typically using a clustered index).

In your case, I don't think you added a clustered index, which probably means that the data is stored in a heap. This essentially would mean SQL Server will return data in an unpredictable manner. The order it returns the data in now might change in the future, which would mean you would end up with users possibly complaining about the data looking "off".

If you want predictable results on the sort order, use an `ORDER BY` clause at all times.

In your case, this would be the full query to use:

```
SELECT 
   Name 
FROM 
   Client_Master 
WHERE 
   Name LIKE'%" + txtname.text + "%'" 
ORDER BY 
   NAME ASC;
```

The `ASC` in this case hints the results should be sorted in Ascending (A-Z) order. If you want to accomplish it the other way around (Z-A), use `DESC` instead of `ASC`.

Comment: If records are  Jaydeep,Jaydeep patel and Pankaj... then i search with your query and type "p" in textbox, then first record sholud be Pankaj..but it displaying Jaydeep, Jaydeep patel and then Pankaj...pankaj should be first in search name..

Comment: @user1425063 - But it should still show the other records as well? Or only those starting with a P?

Comment: I want all record containing 'P' but first it should display start with 'P' and after remaining that contain 'P' in word...